# Appbar title color does not change with theme

Tags: android, flutter

here is my ThemeData:

```
ThemeData(
      // Define the default brightness and colors.
      primaryColor: const Color(0xFF009688),
      primaryColorDark: const Color(0xFF00796B),
      primaryColorLight: const Color(0xFFB2DFDB),
      textTheme: TextTheme(
        titleLarge: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16.sp,
          color: theme.primaryColor,
          fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
        ),
        titleMedium: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14.sp,
          color: theme.primaryColor,
          fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
        ),
        titleSmall: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 12.sp,
          color: theme.primaryColor,
          fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
        ),
        bodyLarge: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14.sp, fontFamily: 'OpenSans', color: theme.primaryColor),
        bodyMedium: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12.sp, fontFamily: 'OpenSans', color: theme.primaryColor),
        bodySmall: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 8.sp, fontFamily: 'OpenSans', color: theme.primaryColor),
      ))
```

and here is my AppBar:

```
AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      title: Row(
        children: [
          IconButton(
              color: theme.primaryColor,
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new)),
          SizedBox(
            width: 2.w,
          ),
              Text(
            'The Title',
            style: TextStyle(color: theme.primaryColor),
          )
        ],
      ))
```

I can change the app theme anywhere in the app and `theme.primaryColor` works but it does not work here on the AppBar title for some reason. The problem is in this line of code:

```
Text(
            'The Title',
            style: TextStyle(color: theme.primaryColor),
          )
```

but the exact same code works everywhere but here in the title! the title uses default flutter color which is blue. I tried to use apply() function and also tried to style it directyly like this:

```
style: theme.textTheme.titleMedium,
```

but that shows as black!!
I also tried changing title text style which is also not working! if I apply the color directly to it like `Color(0xFF009688)` it will work! but I want to use the theme object.

(I have a theme object from ThemeData named theme)

Comment: you should try giving the theme.primaryColor to the for foregroundColor property of AppBar

Comment: it does not work